# SyntaxError unexpected token { when using json object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` error when trying to use a JSON object in JavaScript.

My code is now like this:

```
$bedrijven            = "
select
  cnt.id, cnt.title, cnt.introtext, cnt.ordering, cnt.state, f.item_id,
  max(case when f.field_id = 3 then f.value end) as plaats,
  max(case when f.field_id = 1 then f.value end) as straat
from snm_fields_values f
join snm_content cnt
on cnt.id = f.item_id
where cnt.state = 1
group by f.item_id
order by f.item_id, plaats, straat";
$bedrijvencon       = $conn->query($bedrijven);
while($bedrijven    = $bedrijvencon->fetch_assoc()){
  $jsonobject .= json_encode($bedrijven);
}
```

Then in my footer I use the following:

```
<script>
   var bedrijven = <? echo $jsonobject; ?>;
   console.log(bedrijven);
 </script>
```

If I click on the error line in my console, this is shown:

```
var bedrijven = {"id":"10","title":"P. Vis B.V.","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"10","plaats":"Heenvliet","straat":"Drie\u00ebndijk 1a"}{"id":"3","title":"CijferAdvies Nissewaard","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"1","state":"1","item_id":"3","plaats":"Heenvliet","straat":"Ridderstraat 5"}{"id":"4","title":"\u201cHet Huidhuys\u201d Afslank- en schoonheidsinstituut","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"4","plaats":"Zuidland","straat":"Breedstraat 2"}{"id":"5","title":"Bouwbedrijf van de Water","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"5","plaats":"Heevliet","straat":"Polyanderweg 2"}{"id":"6","title":"Studio NewMedia B.V.","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"6","plaats":"Spijkenisse","straat":"Goudenregenplein 1 - Unit 38"}{"id":"7","title":"Taxi Overgaauw","introtext":"<p><a href=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\"><\/a><a href=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/a><\/p>\r\n<p><a href=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"http:\/\/www.taxiovergaauw.nl\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/a><\/p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"7","plaats":"Zuidland","straat":"Langeweg 2b"}{"id":"8","title":"Moree","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"8","plaats":"Simonshaven","straat":"Ring 2"}{"id":"9","title":"Molengraaf Makelaardij","introtext":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet interdum enim vel volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ullamcorper neque a porttitor malesuada. Etiam pharetra eget nisl sit amet pharetra. Etiam a mi eget justo rutrum euismod. Praesent ligula lorem, consequat in suscipit sit amet, fermentum eu risus. Quisque sed lorem porttitor, rutrum arcu ut, cursus est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris iaculis nisl non gravida dapibus. Nulla at tellus eleifend, vehicula lorem at, lacinia ex. Nam a volutpat dolor, non accumsan lectus. Praesent porta, purus eu consequat pharetra, eros nulla dignissim ipsum, a euismod justo metus in orci.<\/p>\r\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel aliquam nulla, ut elementum urna. Pellentesque posuere eros vitae neque auctor semper. Quisque elit leo, congue non posuere nec, pharetra a velit. Morbi quam lacus, consequat vel euismod a, ullamcorper vitae augue. Integer in nulla euismod diam ornare tempor. Donec ut rutrum urna. Morbi vel efficitur lorem. Sed porttitor risus et urna facilisis, vel pellentesque nisi fermentum. Nam tempus tortor a venenatis auctor.<\/p>","ordering":"0","state":"1","item_id":"9","plaats":"Zuidland","straat":"Mr. P.J. Oudweg 56"};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine:

```
var foo = { a: 1 };
```

But you are outputting:

```
var foo = { a: 1 }{ a: 1 }{ a : 1 };
```

If you want to have a group of objects, then you need to put them into an array.

```
$data = [];
while($bedrijven    = $bedrijvencon->fetch_assoc()){
   array_push($data, $bedrijven);
}
$jsonobject = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: or shortcut php syntax for push `$data[] = $bedrijven`

Comment: Thanks! This gives me the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine multiple json strings by just concatenating them. You have to aggregate them into an array. You could solve this by doing something like this

```
$t = [];
while($bedrijven = $bedrijvencon->fetch_assoc()){
  $t[] = $bedrijven;
}
$jsonobject = json_encode($t);
```